# Deserializing Prometheus `remote_write` Protobuf output in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, prometheus

I'm experimenting (for the first time) with Prometheus. I've setup Prometheus to send messages to a local flask server:

```
remote_write:
  - url: "http://localhost:5000/metric"
```

I'm able to read the incoming bytes, however, I'm not able to convert the incoming messages to any meaningful data.

I'm very new to Prometheus (and Protobuf!) so I'm not sure what the best approach is. I would rather not use a third party package, but want to **learn and understand the Protobuf de/serialization myself**.

I tried copying the `metrics.proto` definitions from the [Prometheus GitHub](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/prompb/io/prometheus/client/metrics.proto) and compiling them with `protoc`. I tried importing the `metrics_pb2.py` file and parsing the incoming message:

```py
read_metric = metrics_pb2.Metric()
read_metric.ParseFromString(request.data)
```

I also tried using the `remote.proto` definitions (specifically `WriteRequest`) which also didn't work:

```py
read_metric = remote_pb2.WriteRequest()
read_metric.ParseFromString(request.data)
```

This results in:
`google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message`

So I suspect that I'm using the wrong Protobuf definitions?

I would really appreciate any help & advice on this!

To provide some more context for what I'm attempting to accomplish:

I'm trying to stream data from multiple Prometheus instances to a message queue so they can be passed to a machine learning model.
I'm using online training with an active learning model, and I want the data to be (near) real-time. That's why I thought the `remote_write` functionality is the best approach rather than continuously scraping each instance. If you have any other ideas on how I can build this system, feel free to share - I've just been playing around with it for a couple days, so I'm open to any feedback!

ANSWER EDIT:

I had to first decompress the data using snappy, thanks larsks!:

```py
bytes = request.data
decompressed = snappy.uncompress(bytes)

read_metric = remote_pb2.WriteRequest()
read_metric.ParseFromString(decompressed)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `remote.proto` document is the correct protobuf specification. You may find [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LPhVRSFkGNSuU1fBd81ulhsCPR4hkSZyyBj1SZ8fWOM/edit#) useful, which explicitly defines the remote write protocol. That document includes the "official" protobuf specification, and mentions that:

> The remote write request MUST be encoded using Google Protobuf 3, and MUST use the schema defined above.  Note [the Prometheus implementation](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/v2.24.0/prompb/remote.proto) uses [gogoproto optimisations](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) - for receivers written in languages other than Golang the gogoproto types MAY be substituted for line-level equivalents.

The document also notes that the body of remote write requests is compressed:

> The remote write request in the body of the HTTP POST MUST be compressed with [Google’s Snappy](https://github.com/google/snappy).  The block format MUST be used - the framed format MUST NOT be used.

So before you can parse the request body you'll need to find a Python solution for decompressing snappy-compressed data.

(I found a link to that google doc from [this article](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/05/26/the-future-of-prometheus-remote-write/) that talks about the development of the remote write protocol.)

Comment: The problem was indeed me completely overlooking the snappy compression. I was too focussed on the definition files. Thank you for taking the time to help!